# Trying to create a minimalist pure js app with rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Trying to create a minimalist pure js app with rxjs.

Flow:

1. npm install rxjs
2. index.html
3. myscript.js

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">    
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js" ></script> 
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>    
</body>
</html>
```

myscript.js:

```
rxjs.Observable.FromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
    .subscribe(()=> console.log("text!"));
```

I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: rxjs.Observable.FromEvent is not a function"

attempt to import failed:

> import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent'; //SyntaxError: Unexpected string

or

> import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';  //SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

What am I doing wrong? How to try rxjs on pure js?

Comment: Try `import { from, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: For CDN, you can use unpkg:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>`
Then,
```javascript
   const { range } = rxjs;
   const { map, filter } = rxjs.operators;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For RxJS v6 take factory functions from `rxjs` and operators from `rxjs.operators`.

Here's an example with a CDN source:

```js
var { fromEvent } = rxjs;
var { map } = rxjs.operators;


var theButton = document.getElementById('the-btn');

fromEvent(theButton, 'click').pipe(
  // pipe some operators here
  map(() => Date.now())
).subscribe(date => {
  console.log('Clicked at ' + date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<button
  id="the-btn"
  >Clicker</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much